# How can I programatically iterate though bindinglist

Tags: vb.net

I have a class that inherits a `BindingList`:

```
Public Class clsAccountManagers
    Inherits BindingList(Of clsAccountManager)
```

How can I programmatically iterate though list contained in an instance of the `clsAccountManagers`?

(I've created a class like this to encapsulate some rules but also hold records of type `clsAccountManager`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've inherited from `BindingList<T>`, your instance of `clsAccountManagers` *is iterable*. For example, you can do this:

```
Dim managers As New clsAccountManagers()

For Each manager In managers
    ' do something
Next
```

If you need to perform something *within* `clsAccountManagers`, the underlying collection property you're looking for is named `Items`, which is a `Collection<T>`.

You can easily do things with it from within `clsAccountManagers`, such as:

```
Public Class clsAccountManagers
    Inherits BindingList(Of clsAccountManager)

   Public Sub DoSomethingWithInternalList()
       For Each item In Items
           ' Do Something
       Next
   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Clear and workable.  MANY thanks. :-)